# Swift - webview wont load

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swift3

I am using swift 3 and I am trying to load a webview programmatically like so:

```
let webview = UIWebView()

            webview.scalesPageToFit = true
            webview.autoresizesSubviews = true
            webview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

            webview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800)
            webview.delegate = self

            let localUrl = String(format:"http://www.google.com")
            let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: localUrl)

            webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))

            self.view.addSubview(webview)
```

but all I get is a blank white screen. I get no errors at all, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
et webview = UIWebView()

    webview.scalesPageToFit = true
    webview.autoresizesSubviews = true
    webview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    webview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 800)
    webview.delegate = self


    webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))

    self.view.addSubview(webview)
```

That works for me, although it doesn't fit properly, on the iPhone 7 simulator unless you change the web view frame to `webview.frame = self.view.frame`  You were trying to turn a string into a file url and then load the file url instead of a normal url.  Also, recently, Apple made it so http://whatever.com doesn't work, you need to use https://whatever.com.

Comment: "You were trying to turn a string into a file url and then load the file url instead of a normal url. Also, recently, Apple made it so http://whatever.com doesn't work, you need to use https://whatever.com." Remarkably similar to what I already said.

Comment: Sorry, I thought adding the code snippet would make it a little clearer.

Comment: Agreed about that, for sure.

Comment: Sorry for copying it, next time if there's a part that's similar to someone else, I'll point it out.

Comment: Sounds fine. You could, for example, have started your answer by referring to my answer. You have every right to improve on another answer by showing code.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `http://www.google.com` is not a file URL. So you cannot make a `fileURL` out of it. Just make a plain URL.

Another problem, on iOS 9 and 10, is that you cannot, by default, load an `http` URL. You have to use `https`.